# C: How do I make a makefile that allows linking to an external library?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, makefile

Like, I think I'm close... just not sure what I'm doing wrong,

```
cfann : main.o
    main.o -l libfann

main.o : main.c
    gcc -c main.c

clean: 
    rm -rf *o cfann
```

I get this error:

```
main.o -l libfann
make: main.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [cfann] Error 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
cfann : main.o
    main.o -l libfann
```

to:

```
cfann : main.o
    gcc main.o -lfann -L/usr/local/lib -o cfann
```

This assumes that libfann.o is in /usr/local/lib - change the -L path above if it's actually somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace:

```
cfann : main.o
    main.o -l libfann
```

with something like:

```
cfann : main.o
    gcc -o cfann -L/path/to/libs main.o -lfann
```

`-L` allows you to specify (multiple) paths to search for the libraries and `-l` lists the library names. The `lib` is normally prefixed for you, as are the possible extensions such as `.a` or `.so`.

What your original makefile is doing is trying to *run* `main.o` as a command, rather than the `gcc` that it should be running.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cfann : main.o

main.o : main.c
    gcc -c main.c -lfann

clean: 
    rm -rf *o cfann
```

Or, maybe without the empty cfann line

```
cfann : main.c
    gcc -c main.c -lfann

clean: 
    rm -rf *o cfann
```